# UDP multi-clients

Tags: java, android, networking, udp, wifi

At the moment I have a Java UDP server working on Android, the server has a datagramSocket on port which it first just listens for a client to connect, a client will create a new datagramSocket on the same port, and send a packet over asking to connect, once the server receives this, it takes the IP uses to send the message, and then just sends a message pack with a position of a block, while the client also sends back it's own position of a block,

Information, the application allows multiple users to connect to one host, this host will take in all the positions from the clients and then broadcast them out, there are other ways to do it, but I want to do it this way for research.

But anyways down to the question, My application will hopefully handle 8 users, as this application works for wifihotspot. how would i go about allowing multiple clients to connect, send data and receive data? I have the code already to allow one client to connect, and the host will send out data to that client, but if I try to connect another client i get an error, Here is my code for the server and the client

P.S. there maybe some debugging code in there as I need to clear that out.

**Server code**

```
package com.example.gelorph_v1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import org.apache.http.conn.util.InetAddressUtils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class gameServer extends Thread {

    /**
     * Sets up a server for Android applciation
     */
    private static final String TAG = "GameServer";
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private int port = 50000;
    private int players = 0;
    private ArrayList<gameObject> assets = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<InetAddress> address = new ArrayList();
    private boolean wait = false;
    private Context contextHolder = null;

    //Make an array, this array will hold all the positions
    //the clients sent to it,
    //using the ID number, it will store it in a array block
    //and the "host" can just return it and use that

    public gameServer( Context context ) throws IOException
    {
        contextHolder = context;
        socket = new DatagramSocket( port );
        Log.d(TAG, "Server was setup");
    }

    public DatagramSocket rtnSocket(){ return socket; }

    private String getLocalIPAddress()
    {
        try
        {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); nis.hasMoreElements();)
            {
                NetworkInterface ni = nis.nextElement();
                Log.v(TAG, "NetworkInterface = " + ni.getDisplayName());
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> ips = ni.getInetAddresses(); ips.hasMoreElements();)
                {
                    InetAddress ip = ips.nextElement();
                    String s = ip.getHostAddress();
                    Log.v(TAG, "InetAddress = " + s);
                    if (!ip.isLoopbackAddress())
                    {
                                if(InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(s)) return s;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
                Log.e(TAG,"getLocalIPAddress()", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void passClient( gameObject clientTemp )
    {
        assets.add( clientTemp );
    }

    protected void doInBackground()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InetAddress client = null;
        boolean run = true;
        String data = "";
        DatagramPacket packet = null;
        while( run )
        {
            if( data.equalsIgnoreCase( "" ) )
            {
                /*Log.d(TAG, "waiting for clients");
                String msg = "waiting";
                int msgLength = msg.length();
                byte[] message = msg.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( message, msgLength, client, port );
                try 
                {
                    socket.send( p );
                } 
                catch (IOException e2) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error with sending");
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }*/
            }

            //Send some data
            if( data.equalsIgnoreCase( "connect" ) && wait == true )
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "ID send :" + packet.getAddress());
                address.add( packet.getAddress() );

                players += 1;
                String msg = String.valueOf( players );
                int msgLength = msg.length();
                byte[] message = msg.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( message, msgLength, packet.getAddress(), port );
                try 
                {
                    socket.send( p );
                    wait = false;
                } 
                catch (IOException e2) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error with sending");
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                    data = "";
                }
            }

            //if( /*data.equalsIgnoreCase( "position" )*/ address.size() > 0 )
            //{
                //Create for loop to create the string
                String msg = "";
                msg = players + "#";
                for(int i = 0; i < players; i++)
                {
                            msg += + i + ":" + assets.get(i).returnPosX() + ":" + assets.get(i).returnPosY() + ":"; 
                }
                //msg = String.valueOf( 
                //      players + ":" + 
                //      "1:" + assets.get(0).returnPosX() + ":" + assets.get(0).returnPosY() );
                int msgLength = msg.length();
                byte[] message = msg.getBytes();
                for(int i = 0; i < address.size() ; i++)
                {
                    DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( message, msgLength, address.get(i), port );
                    try 
                    {
                        socket.send( p );
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e2) 
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error with sending");
                        e2.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
                //Log.d(TAG, "Data sent is:" + msg);
            //}

            data = " ";

            //Receive some data
            if( wait == false )
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
                try 
                {
                    socket.receive( packet );
                    wait = true;
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                data = new String( buf, 0, packet.getLength() );
                Log.d(TAG, "Data received from :" + packet.getAddress() + ", holds this value: " + data);
                //Upset each asset with the data sent
            }


            //Log.d(TAG, "Data received was :" + data);

            try 
            {
                this.sleep( 25 );
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d(TAG, "Error with trying to sleep");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Error with while run value");
    }

    public int returnPlayers(){ return players; }
}
```

**Client code**

```
package com.example.gelorph_v1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.DhcpInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class gameClient extends Thread {

    private static final String TAG = "gameClient";
    private gameServer server;
    private boolean rdyForPlay = false;
    private gameObject[] assets = new gameObject[8];
    private int ID = 0;
    private int port = 50000;
    private InetAddress address;
    private maths cal = new maths();
    private Context contextHolder;
    private boolean host = false;
    private DatagramSocket socket = null;
    private int totalPlayers = 0;

    public gameClient( boolean serverTag, Context context )
    {
        if( serverTag == true)
        {
            host = true;
            try 
            {
                contextHolder = context;
                server = new gameServer( contextHolder );
                this.start();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Could not start server");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            contextHolder = context;
            connectToServer();
            this.start();
        }
    }

    public void connectToServer()
    {
        //Send a connect message to the server
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket( port );
            byte[] bufer = new byte[256];
            String msg = "connect";
            int msgLength = msg.length();
            bufer = msg.getBytes();
            InetAddress address;
            address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.59");
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( bufer, bufer.length , address, port );
            socket.send( p );

        } catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Receive the message back
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
        try 
        {
            socket.receive( packet );
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String data = new String( buf, 0, packet.getLength() );

        ID = Integer.parseInt( data );
        setUpClient();

        Log.d(TAG, "Data received was :" + ID);
    }

    public void setUpClient()
    {
        gameObject temp = new gameObject(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(contextHolder.getResources(), R.drawable.player), 250, 300);
        assets[ID] = temp;
        if( host == true )
        {
            server.passClient( temp );
        }
    }

    public void sendTouchEvent(float xSet, float ySet)
    {
        assets[ID].setPosition( xSet, ySet );
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if( host == true ) { setUpClient(); server.start(); }
        rdyForPlay = true;
        boolean run = true;
        boolean setupPlayer = false;
        while( run )
        {
            //Tell the server to give position of players
            //if( setupPlayer == true )
            //{
            //  setUpClient();
            //  setupPlayer = false;
            //}

            if( host == false )
            {
                try {
                    if(socket == null)
                    {
                        socket = new DatagramSocket( port );
                    }
                    byte[] bufer = new byte[256];
                    //String msg = "position";
                    String msg = ID +":"+ assets[ID].returnPosX() +":"+ assets[ID].returnPosY();
                    int msgLength = msg.length();
                    bufer = msg.getBytes();
                    InetAddress address;
                    address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.59");
                    DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( bufer, bufer.length , address, port );
                    socket.send( p );

                } catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error with unknown host");
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error with socket");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error with sending/receiving data");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
                try 
                {
                    socket.receive( packet );
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String data = new String( buf, 0, packet.getLength() );
                //Split the string up
                String[] dataArray = data.split("#");
                int newTotalPlayers = Integer.parseInt( dataArray[0] );
                if( newTotalPlayers != totalPlayers )
                {
                    Log.d(TAG," what is total amount of players:" + newTotalPlayers);
                    if( newTotalPlayers == 1 )
                    {
                        newPlayer( 0 );
                        totalPlayers = newTotalPlayers;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newPlayer( newTotalPlayers );
                        totalPlayers = newTotalPlayers;
                    }
                    //if( ID == 0 && host == false)
                    //{
                    //  ID = newTotalPlayers;
                    //  setupPlayer = true;
                    //}
                }
                //Do a for loop to go through dataArray
                for( int i = 0; i < totalPlayers; i++)
                {
                    String[] pos = dataArray[(i + 1)].split(":");
                    if( Integer.parseInt( pos[(i*3)] ) == ID )
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Do nothing please");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        assets[i].setPosition( Integer.parseInt( pos[(i*3) + 1] ), Integer.parseInt( pos[(i*3) + 2] ) );
                    }
                }

            }

            //host
            if( host == true )
            {
                /*if( server.returnPlayers() != totalPlayers )
                {
                    Log.d(TAG," what is total amount of players:" + server.returnPlayers());
                    newPlayer( server.returnPlayers() );
                    totalPlayers = server.returnPlayers();
                    //if( ID == 0 && host == false)
                    //{
                    //  ID = newTotalPlayers;
                    //  setupPlayer = true;
                    //}
                }*/
            }

        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Error with run value");
    }

    private void newPlayer( int idOfNewPlayer )
    {
        gameObject temp = new gameObject(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(contextHolder.getResources(), R.drawable.new_player), 250, 300);
        assets[ idOfNewPlayer ] = temp;
    }

    private void updateAssets()
    {

    }

    public gameObject[] rtnAssets(){ return assets; }
    public int rtnID(){ return ID; }
    public boolean rtnRdy(){ return rdyForPlay; }
    public gameServer rtnServer(){ return server; }
    public boolean rtnHost(){ return host; }
    public void stopServers()
    {
        socket.close();
        server.rtnSocket().close();
    }
}
```

Don't worry to much about a new block being created when a client joins and what not, I'm just trying to work out what is the best way to allow multiple users? and most importantly how? If anyone could point me in the right direction, or give some simple example code that would be great.

Comment: Remember that UDP is _connectionless_, a client just sends its data to the server. It's up to the server to keep track of the clients that sends it data. The server can do that by having a list of all unique clients sending data to it, and send data back to the correct client.

Comment: all 8 clients will have different IP addresses, the data it receives, could i use that to ID the client and then tell were to store the data that was received?

Comment: Normally, IP-address and port-number is used to distinguish between clients, if all clients are on different hosts then using only IP-address may be enough.

Comment: all clients will be connected to the same router (wifi-hotspot). can this work?

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Sweet, I thought I may have to make like 8 threads for each one :) or new ports for each client, well cheers for help, I will give this a go tomorrow, I will comment again if I get a error or a problem :)

Comment: "A client will create a new datagramSocket on the same port" Why? Same port as what? What was wrong with its original datagram socket?

Comment: Joachim, as the server will be receiving from up to 8 different clients, won't I need to tell the server to wait on socket.receive? because depending on which client gets in queue first, will be udpated, and some may never get their position updated, I mean I havent tried but will this happen? would I need to create a for loop to wait to received from all the clients connected, then update the positions on the server?